# Issue importing JSON data into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, database, file

I've written a script that imports paginated JSON data from an api, encodes the data to UTF-8 and then writes it to a file.

I need to iterate over the data in the file to create records in my database, but am running to an error loading the file so I can do so.

The stack trace isn't telling me much about what's wrong; any help would be greatly appreciated!

code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'faker'

#imports APR User data from the zendesk api, iterates through it and populates the database with it. 


uri = URI.parse("https://aprtechsupport.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request.basic_auth("cbradford@blah.com", "blah32")

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

@response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end


res = @response.body 
res.force_encoding("utf-8")
resEncoded = JSON.parse(res)

users = resEncoded



#data = {}
#data.merge(users)

results = []
results << resEncoded

puts results 

while users["next_page"]
 newUri = users["next_page"]
 uriLoop = URI.parse(newUri)
 puts newUri
 requestLoop = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uriLoop)
 requestLoop.content_type = "application/json"
 requestLoop.basic_auth("cbradford@blah.com", "blah32")

 req_optionsLoop = {
   use_ssl: uriLoop.scheme == "https",
 }

 @responseLoop = Net::HTTP.start(uriLoop.hostname, uriLoop.port, req_optionsLoop) do |http|
  http.request(requestLoop)
  end
  dataEncoded = @responseLoop.body
  dataEncoded.force_encoding("utf-8")
  resLoop = JSON.parse(dataEncoded)
  results << resLoop
  updateUri = resLoop["next_page"]
  users["next_page"] = updateUri
end



puts "hash created Successfully!"

puts results

File.write('blahzendeskusers1.json', results)


puts "File Created Successfully!"


file = File.read('blahzendeskusers1.json')

usersLoop = JSON.load(file)["users"]

usersLoop.each do |a|
    User.find_or_create_by(:zendesk_id_int => a["id"], :url => a["url"], :name => a["name"], :email => a["email"],
        :phone => a["phone"], :role => a["role"], :default_group_id => a["default_group_id"], :external_id => a["external_id"],
        :tags => a["tags"]
        )
end
```

stack trace:

```
>     /Users/christopherbradford/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in
> `parse'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in
> `parse'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:335:in
> `load'
> /Users/christopherbradford/railsProjects/aprzendeskdata/db/seeds.rb:84:in
> `<top (required)>'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in
> `load_seed'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:270:in
> `load_seed'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:184:in
> `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in
> `block in execute'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in
> `each'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in
> `execute'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in
> `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in
> `mon_synchronize'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in
> `invoke_with_call_chain'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in
> `invoke'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in
> `invoke_task'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
> `block (2 levels) in top_level'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
> `each'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
> `block in top_level'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in
> `run_with_threads'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in
> `top_level'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in
> `block in run'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in
> `standard_exception_handling'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in
> `run'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in
> `<top (required)>'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
> /Users/christopherbradford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rake:23:in
> `<main>' Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Sample File Data:

```
{"users"=>[{"id"=>360403052546, "url"=>"https://aprtechsupport.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/360403052546.json", "name"=>"Caller +1 (650) 434-4313", "email"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2018-03-05T19:36:00Z", "updated_at"=>"2018-03-05T19:36:00Z", "time_zone"=>"Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "phone"=>"+16504344313", "shared_phone_number"=>false, "photo"=>nil, "locale_id"=>1, "locale"=>"en-US", "organization_id"=>nil, "role"=>"end-user", "verified"=>true, "external_id"=>nil, "tags"=>[], "alias"=>nil, "active"=>true, "shared"=>false, "shared_agent"=>false, "last_login_at"=>nil, "two_factor_auth_enabled"=>false, "signature"=>nil, "details"=>nil, "notes"=>nil, "role_type"=>nil, "custom_role_id"=>nil, "moderator"=>false, "ticket_restriction"=>"requested", "only_private_comments"=>false, "restricted_agent"=>true, "suspended"=>false, "chat_only"=>false, "default_group_id"=>nil, "user_fields"=>{}}, {"id"=>360404721566, "url"=>"https://aprtechsupport.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/360404721566.json", "name"=>"renglehart", "email"=>"renglehart@apr.com", "created_at"=>"2018-03-06T00:29:39Z", "updated_at"=>"2018-03-07T19:00:58Z", "time_zone"=>"Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "phone"=>nil, "shared_phone_number"=>nil, "photo"=>nil, "locale_id"=>1, "locale"=>"en-US", "organization_id"=>nil, "role"=>"end-user", "verified"=>true, "external_id"=>nil, "tags"=>[], "alias"=>nil, "active"=>true, "shared"=>false, "shared_agent"=>false, "last_login_at"=>"2018-03-07T19:00:58Z", "two_factor_auth_enabled"=>false, "signature"=>nil, "details"=>nil, "notes"=>nil, "role_type"=>nil, "custom_role_id"=>nil, "moderator"=>false, "ticket_restriction"=>"requested", "only_private_comments"=>false, "restricted_agent"=>true, "suspended"=>false, "chat_only"=>false, "default_group_id"=>nil, "user_fields"=>{}},
```

Comment: I would start by breaking this up into methods or classes that do one job each so that you can actually test each part separatly. I doubt that anyone is will to help you dig through a long proceedural rant.

Comment: The "Sample File Data" is not valid JSON.  Usually, pagination of JSON results in multiple bits of valid JSON. In any case, it's not clear how this "Sample" relates to the complete data.  It would probably help if you could follow the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Which line is line 84? That is the one causing the error. Some json is malformed. Either the API is returning bad json (weird?), but most likely it is _not_ in UTF8?